# I'm having trouble with this basic differentiation of Lagrangian:

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

This pertains to economics but that's largely irrelevant as I'm having trouble with the math. The utility function, in this case person A's, is being maximized.

Production function of x:
$$
x=f\left(y_{s}^{A}+y_{s}^{B}\right)
$$

Two 'utility' functions for person A and B:
$$
U^{A}\left(x, y^{A *}-y_{s}^{A}\right)
$$
$$
U^{B}\left(x, y^{B *}-y_{s}^{B}\right)
$$
Lagrangian:
$$
\mathscr{L}=U^{A}\left(x, y^{A *}-y_{s}^{A}\right)+\lambda\left[U^{B}\left(x, y^{B *}-y_{s}^{B}\right)-K\right]
$$

First-order conditions is where I get lost and  do not understand:
$$
\begin{array}{l}{\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial y_{s}^{A}}=U_{1}^{A} f^{\prime}-U_{2}^{A}+\lambda U_{1}^{B} f^{\prime}=0} \\ {\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial y_{s}^{B}}=U_{1}^{A} f^{\prime}-\lambda U_{2}^{B}+\lambda U_{1}^{B} f^{\prime}=0}\end{array}
$$

Mathematically I do not follow how the first-order conditions come about from the provided Lagrangian. Just looking at the top equation, $
\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial y_{s}^{A}}$, where do these three components come from when differentiating with respect to $
y_{S}^{A}
$?

Comment: If $x = f(y_{s}^{A}+y_{s}^{B})$ is a function of $y_{s}^{A}, y_{s}^{B}$, then replace $x$ with $f$ in the definition of the Lagrangian. Then differentiate. I'm assuming $U_{1}, U_{2}$ means 'differentiate with respect to the first argument'.

Comment: Right exactly. So how is it that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are both in the same expression? Differentiating with respect to the 1st argument minus the derivative with respect to the 2nd argument?

Comment: Because $y_{s}^{A}$ appears in _both_ arguments of $U^{A}$ and in the second argument, you have $y^{A*} \color{red}- y_{s}^{A}$. You need to use the chain rule.